# My unique Id in form with multiple inputs can't be saved in my database Php

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, input

:) So i want to make a form with multiple inputs that are stored in the database with a unique id for every single input.  My prblem is that if I save only one dynamic input the unique id is saved to my database but if i try for more than one it cant be saved. I tried many things but it dosent working. Can samone help.

PHP code

```
$values=array();
for($i=0 ;$i < count($_POST['fields']); $i++) {
    $supply_unique_id=uniqid();
    $values[] = '("' . $_POST['fields'][$i] . '","' . $supply_unique_id . '")';
}

$sql="INSERT INTO supplies (supply,supply_unique_id) 
                VALUES " . implode(',', $values);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on the query shows you what?

Comment: `VALUES (....)` note the brackets

Comment: Unique `id`'s are normally made by using the database column option `Auto Increment`. Dont reinvent a well tested and working solution

Comment: yet another *"talk amongst ourselves"* question @RiggsFolly

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably will be until a rep hound makes the effort to _D.I.F.M_

Comment: Thansk a lot @RiggsFolly  I saw waht  the problem is.

Comment: Please post an answer then, or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from `uniqid()` function it was duplicating the entry for key `'supply_unique_id'` so I changed it to `uniqid(rand(), true)`. It also works with `md5()` function. So this is the only thing I changed `$supply_unique_id=uniqid(rand(), true);`